# How to show distance between two or more route on openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap

Have anyone work on show distance between two route like rail and road
Please have a look below image

[We need to implement like this on openstreetmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaPi3.png)

Comment: What is the expected distance in your example? ~200 km?

Comment: I have distance both route like via train 2000 km and via road 1500 km, So we need to show map of both route